# Batching PageView in Google Analytics in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

Currently, I try to 10 page views(which may be different pages) and flush to Google Analytics at once.
By setting setDebug(true), I can see the http request sent to Google Analytics. It is funny to find that 10 http request send at dispatching instead of one big http request....
How to have a big http request in order to dispatch the cached page views?